# Break out a WHILE and then come back the last position in Stored Procedure - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2005

For example I have

// This is just a dummy sample code.

```
WHILE
  BEGIN

     Statement 1
     GOTO RESET
     Statement 2
     GOTO RESET
     Statement 3
     GOTO RESET
  END

RESET:
SET @Var = 1 
// At this point, I need to come back my last position in the WHILE LOOP
```

My question are 

1. Is it possible?

2. If yes, how can I do that?

Thank you very much

Comment: `WHILE` and `GOTO` should be avoided in T-SQL code because they are non-relational and slow. Use set-based operations instead.

Comment: @AnthonyFaull there are always exceptions, sometimes you have to use while and goto.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `GOTO` syntax. You define for `Label` and then you `GOTO` that Label. Like this:

```
DECLARE @test INT=1

SomeName:
    print 'test'

IF @test=1
BEGIN
    SET @test=2
    GOTO SomeName
END
```

This will `PRINT 'test'` two times

Reference [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180188.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

SQL supports `GOTO`/`LABEL`:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180188.aspx

Not entirely sure why you would need such elaborate flow control in your stored proc. Maybe try splitting the stored proc into different procedures?

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use a `TRY...CATCH` block for this.

```
DECLARE @i int

SET @i = 1

WHILE @i <= 5
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        IF @i = 3 RAISERROR('Three is an incorrect value', 11, 1)

        PRINT 'Ok'
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        PRINT 'Error'
    END CATCH

    SET @i = @i + 1
END
```